# How can I find an orthogonal matrix in R?

Tags: r

I want to find an orthogonal matrix (`G`) in R such that
`G'CG=L=diag(l1,l2,...lp)`
where `l1>l2>...>lp>0` are the eigen values of known matrix `C`.
I find a matrix with using code `eigen(C)$vectors`  but the result matrix (`L`) is not a diagonal one. Is there anyone who can help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: can you post sample `C`?

Comment: did you try `?svd` function?

Answer (score 9):

Your only restriction on `C` shown is that all eigenvalues are positive.  However, this is equivalent to saying that `C` is positive definite.

In that case, given `e <- eigen(C)`, we have the following:

```
Q = e$vectors
l = e$values

Conj(t(Q)) = Q^-1

Q %*% diag(l) %*% Conj(t(Q)) = C
```

Equivalently:

```
diag(l) = Conj(t(Q)) %*% C %*% Q
```

As the eigenvalues in `l` are stored in decreasing order, you are done.

Comment: Thanks. I try it but I could not succeed. Do I need a special package? `Conj` and `Cong` are unknown function in my software.

Comment: @user2227801 (1) `Cong` was a typo, which I've fixed. (2) `Conj` is a function in base R: if you using R it should be available to you. (3) If the proposed solution doesn't work for you, you shouldn't "Accept" it .

Comment: Is your matrix `C` actually positive definite?

Comment: @ Josh O'Brien , Yes you are right. I should not accept. diagonal matrix is a matrix which the entries outside the main diagonal (↘) are all zero. but the result is not. In the other hand eigen(C)$vectors is also diag(l).

Comment: @ Matthew Lundberg, Yes, C is a positive definite.

Comment: @user2227801 I don't know what you might mean by "eigen(C)$vectors is also diag(l)".  `diag(eigen(C)$values)` is your diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg, I want to tell that you do not need calculating a new matrix, `eigen(C)$vectors` is a matrix that is true in equation.

Comment: @user2227801 Seems that we have a language problem, as I cannot discern what you're trying to say.  Indeed, `eigen(C)$vectors` is a matrix, and (in the case of a positive-definite input matrix) is the orthogonal matrix that you desire.  There's another matrix here too, `diag(eigen(C)$values)`.  That one is a diagonal matrix (of eigenvalues).